# JFormattedTextField date changes after leaving focus

Tags: java, swing, date, format, jformattedtextfield

i try to deal with a problem relating to my JFormattedTextFields. I need two of them for a small database project. One has to display a date, the other one a currency value.

The field for the currency value works without any problems. Formats input as long as there are no letters in it and the currency sign is at the end of the input (€ / $). Here's my code for that:

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    NumberFormatter nff = new NumberFormatter(nf);
    DefaultFormatterFactory currencyfactory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(nff);
    formattedTextField2.setFormatterFactory(currencyfactory);
    formattedTextField2.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT_OR_REVERT);
    formattedTextField2.setValue(00.00);
```

If i try the same with my date field, the result is a bit confusing. Here's my code for the date field:

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY");
    DateFormatter dateFormatter = new DateFormatter(df);
    DefaultFormatterFactory datefactory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(dateFormatter);
    formattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(datefactory);
    formattedTextField1.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT_OR_REVERT);
    formattedTextField1.setValue(new Date());
```

When i start my test program, todays date is written to the formattedtextfield, for example 28.03.2018. If i change the value to 28.03.2017 and leave the field (with TAB or selecting another field on the form), the value changes to 02.01.2017.

Other examples i tried:

22.10.2015 -> 29.12.2015

25.04.2012 -> 02.01.2012

19.09.1993 -> 04.01.1993

I don't understand that behavior. Normally, the **setFocusLostBehavior** with the COMMIT_OR_REVERT should check, if the user input / field value is a valid value depending on the format of the specific formattedtextfield and his factory. Otherwise it should reset the value to the last valid input/value.

Has someone a tip for me here?

EDIT:

```
public class formattedtextfield {
private JPanel panel_main;
private JFormattedTextField formattedTextField1;
private JFormattedTextField formattedTextField2;

public formattedtextfield() {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY");
    DateFormatter dateFormatter = new DateFormatter(df);
    DefaultFormatterFactory datefactory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(dateFormatter);
    formattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(datefactory);
    formattedTextField1.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT_OR_REVERT);
    formattedTextField1.setValue(new Date());

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    NumberFormatter nff = new NumberFormatter(nf);
    DefaultFormatterFactory currencyfactory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(nff);
    formattedTextField2.setFormatterFactory(currencyfactory);
    formattedTextField2.setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT_OR_REVERT);
    formattedTextField2.setValue(00.00);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("formattedtextfield");
    frame.setContentPane(new formattedtextfield().panel_main);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

This is my whole little test program with one form and the two formattedtextfields.

EDIT2:
I found the solution! It was just a little typo with the SimpleDateFormat. I set the pattern to "dd.MM.YYYY" but it has to be "dd.MM.yyyy". It was the lowercase Y that caused the problem. Holy moly.. Thank you anyway for reading and commenting :)

Does not work:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY");
```

Does work:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your problem.

Comment: This is almost the whole example. I just have one Swing form with two JFormattedTextFields, their initialisation (see two code snippets above) and the auto-generated Main function to start the form. Thats it.

Comment: *"Thats it."* So .. where is that minimal, complete & verifiable example? Include it as an [edit] and that will be the MCVE. Without that, voting to close.

Comment: @AndrewThompson included the whole example as an edit.

Comment: Y -> is the week of year. y -> is the year.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy thanks for the clarification. See EDIT2 in original post. Found the solution minutes ago. :)